# Stemming and highlighting for phrase search

Tags: elasticsearch, highlighting, stemming

My Elasticsearch index is full of large English-text documents. When I search for `"it is rare"`, I get 20 hits with that exact phrase and when I search for `"it is rarely"` I get a different 10. How can I get all 30 hits at once?

I've tried creating creating a multi-field with the english analyzer (below), but if I search in that field then I only get results from parts of phrase (e.g., documents matchin `it` or `is` or `rare`) instead of the whole phrase.

```
"mappings" : {
   ...
      "text" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "fields" : {
          "english" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : true,
            "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
            "analyzer" : "english"
          }
        }
      },
   ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out!

1. Store two fields, one for the text content (`text`) and a sub-field with the English-ified stem words (`text.english`).
2. Create a custom analyzer based off of the [default English analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) which doesn't strip stop words.
3. Highlight both fields and check for each when displaying results to the user.

Here's my index configuration:

```
{
  mappings: {
    documents: {
      properties: {
        title: { type: 'string' },
        text: {
          type: 'string',
          term_vector: 'with_positions_offsets_payloads',
          fields: {
            english: {
              type: 'string',
              analyzer: 'english_nostop',
              term_vector: 'with_positions_offsets_payloads',
              store: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  settings: {
    analysis: {
      filter: {
        english_stemmer: {
          type: 'stemmer',
          language: 'english'
        },
        english_possessive_stemmer: {
          type: 'stemmer',
          language: 'possessive_english'
        }
      },
      analyzer: {
        english_nostop: {
          tokenizer: 'standard',
          filter: [
            'english_possessive_stemmer',
            'lowercase',
            'english_stemmer'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's what a query looks like:

```
{
  query: {
    query_string: {
      query: <query>,
      fields: ['text.english'],
      analyzer: 'english_nostop'
    }
  },
  highlight: {
    fields: {
      'text.english': {}
      'text': {}
    }
  },
}
```